# QDB2 wont compile

Tags: database, qt, db2

How to insert/install QDB2 plugin? (SQLDriver for Qt, for connecting to IBM DB2).

I tried

```
cd $QTDIR/plugins/src/sqldrivers/db2
qmake -o Makefile "INCLUDEPATH+=$DB2DIR/include" "LIBS+=-L$DB2DIR/lib -ldb2"
make
```

But $QTDIR is not defined. Qt was installed with sudo apt-get ... and i dont know where to find folder
Also qmake wont run. Cant recognize mode or options.

Can somebody tell me how i can insert plugin so QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QDB2"); can work

Answer (score 0):

This is a little bit old, but I had similar problems to get this working.
I also found this here via Google, so there might be others facing the same problem.

By the way: $QTDIR is meant to be changed by you to fit your configurations.

I used Qt 5.7.1, IBM's DB2 Express-C edition at version 11.1 and Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 compiling against x64. The instructions are taken from a corresponding [blog post](https://milania.de/blog/Compile_qt%27s_db2_sqldriver_%28QDB2%29) of mine.

Make sure you have everything installed. I use the following paths:

```
C:\Qt\5.7\msvc2015_64\bin: location of the build tool qmake
C:\Qt\5.7\Src: location of Qt's source code (default location when the sources are fetched with the maintenance tool)
C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB: location inside IBM's install directory where the sql library is located
```

If you use different paths, adjust them accordingly in the following build instruction.

1. There is a bug in Qt 5.7.1 (which seems to be fixed in Qt 5.8.0) so that the sources need to be adjusted. Open the file `C:\Qt\5.7\Src\qtbase\src\sql\drivers\db2\qsql_db2.cpp` and change line 1190 to `d->hEnv = reinterpret_cast<SQLHANDLE>(env);` and line 1191 to `d->hDbc = reinterpret_cast<SQLHANDLE>(con);`
2. Open the Visual Studio command line prompt (VS2015 x64 Native Tools-Eingabeaufforderung öffnen) with administration privileges
3. `cd` to the directory `C:\Qt\5.7\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers\db2`
4. Run the command `C:\Qt\5.7\msvc2015_64\bin\qmake "INCLUDEPATH+=C:/progra~1/IBM/SQLLIB/include" "LIBS+=C:/progra~1/IBM/SQLLIB/lib/db2cli.lib"`

   4.1. Adjust the path, if you have installed DB2 to a different directory

   4.2. Make sure you replace `Program Files` with `progra~1` (otherwise there might be some problems due to the space)
5. Run `C:\Qt\5.7\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers\db2>nmake` to build the library. There might be some warnings, but it should work nevertheless. If successful, the produced libs should be located at `C:\Qt\5.7\Src\qtbase\plugins\sqldrivers`
6. Run `C:\Qt\5.7\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers\db2>nmake` install so that the produced libs will be copied to `C:\Qt\5.7\msvc2015_64\plugins\sqldrivers`
7. Start Qt Creator, open the sqlbrowser example project, build and run it. If successful, you should now be able to select the QDB2 driver from the list and connect to your database